# Doctrine distinct createQueryBuilder

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, distinct, symfony-2.1

I am trying to select MAX scores objects for unique user(s).

So user should be distinct and i should receive max score for a user (order), and I need to get other object values like dataAdded for this max score.

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $query->select('DISTINCT s.user, s');
    $query->where('s.challenge = :challenge')->setParameter('challenge', $challenge);

    $query->andWhere('s.date_added BETWEEN :monday AND :sunday')
       ->setParameter('monday', $startDate->format('Y-m-d'))
       ->setParameter('sunday', $endDate->format('Y-m-d'));

    $query->orderBy('s.score', 'DESC');

    //$query->groupBy('s.user');
    $query->setMaxResults($limit);

    $results = $query->getQuery();
```

Does not matter how I try i can't make distinct to work. I have tried group by MAX(s.score) but this will associate random object with max score rather then the same object..

Does anyone have a solution to this? Distinct simply don't seem to work...

Generated query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.user, s FROM Digital\ApplicationBundle\Entity\ChallengeScore s WHERE s.challenge = :challenge AND (s.date_added BETWEEN :monday AND :sunday) ORDER BY s.score DESC
```

But an error ;(

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 'user, s FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression
```

Its worth to mention that user is a relation. When i try this on other files this works fine...

Answer (score 0):

If you need get count distinct values, you can use [countDistinct](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class). But if you must get all distinct values, use [groupBy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods)